# Faulty compilation of string constant in ASM

Tags: assembly, cygwin, nasm

I'm writing a program to get the hashes of certain function-names in ASM.

The function to fetch the string constants is the following:

```
get_strings:
    call get_curr_addr
    pop esi
    add esi, 9
    jmp str_return  

    db "LoadLibraryA"
    db 0x00
```

This produces the following string constant in the bytecode (xxd output):

```
 ...
    00000040: 2424 61c3 e8bc ffff ff5e 83c6 09eb 7d4c  $$a......^....}L
    00000050: 6f61 644c 6962 7261 7279 4100 .... ....  oadLibraryA.
```

OllyDBG interprets this as:

```
ASCII "dLibraryA",0
```

When I change the code to the following:

```
get_strings:
    call get_curr_addr
    pop esi
    add esi, 9
    jmp str_return  

    db "Jibberish"
    db 0x00 
    db "LoadLibraryA"
    db 0x00
```

The compilation is done "right" (the way I expect it to be).

xxd output:

```
...
00000050: 0000 4a69 6262 6572 6973 6800 4c6f 6164  ..Jibberish.Load
00000060: 4c69 6272 6172 7941 00.. .... .... ....  LibraryA.
```

And there's no

```
7d
```

byte anymore in front of the LoadLibraryA string literal.

Ofcourse the debugger now sees the strings as they should be

```
ASCII "Jibberish",0
ASCII "LoadLibraryA",0
```

Is this the cygwin NASM compiler that's acting weird or am I slowly growing mad?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OllyDBG, so I can't say why it won't display the string correctly. I don't really see anything strange with the way the assembler handles your first example though. `eb 7d` is the machine code for `jmp str_return`, which is the last instruction before the `"LoadLibraryA"` string.

Comment: I would suspect that since you've defined your string in the "text" (code) section, OllyDBG is attempting to interpret it as code (as it should), and sees the codes for "Loa" as possibly being an instruction and only defaults to ASCII interpretation when it gets to the "d...". I think this is going to be an artifact of attempting to disassemble mixed code and data no matter what. Is there a specific reason you're not defining your string in a data section?

Comment: I should add that this behavior is not "faulty" or "weird". You put data into a code section (not necessarily a wrong thing to do, depending upon what your goals are) and the debugger's disassembler is doing its best to make sense of it. :)

Comment: This makes complete sense and is probably an interpretation mistake on my behalf. Except for 1  thing which is the following:

In the first example (the one I assumed to be faulty), the hashing function actually pushes the hash for "dLibraryA" on to the stack.

In the second example, the correct hash is returned. If it is indeed the debugger trying to make sense of my somewhat odd coding, shouldn't the result (stack) eventually be the same? I'll rewrite the program to check on the behavior with the constants properly coded in that .data section. 

Thanks for your clarifications!

Comment: @lurker thanks, that did the trick indeed. No particular reason I put it in the code section tbh. I started off with something small and kept adding lines to it until I eventually bumped into this. I'm guessing in the second example, things go well because the last byte before "LoadLibraryA" is the 0x00 from the "Jibberish" string, right?

Comment: In your "Jibberish" example, the disassembler in OllyDBG, couldn't interpret the ASCII codes for "Jib..." as instructions, so gave you the ASCII that you expected. Just lucky. ;)

Comment: @lurker Figures! Thanks a lot for clearing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Lurker and Michael in the comments:

There is no **Problem** apart from the fact that my debugger attempts to interpret the "Loa" part of "LoadLibraryA" as an actual instruction because I've put the string literals in the .text (code) section.

In the second example, this does not reproduce as "Jib" in the "Jibberish" string, can't be translated into an instruction.

Issue is resolved by putting the literals in the .data section (where they **belong**).

In code, the snippet:

```
get_strings:
    call get_curr_addr
    pop esi
    add esi, 9
    jmp str_return  

    db "LoadLibraryA"
    db 0x00
```

Now becomes:

```
get_strings:
    call get_curr_addr
    pop esi
    add esi, 9
    jmp str_return

[SECTION .data]
    db "LoadLibraryA"
    db 0x00
```